# xubuntu - in a bash script find all folders with an emblem

Tags: xubuntu, emblem

I'm using Xubuntu 20.04. I have put emblems on many directories. Is there a way in a bash script to list all directories with emblems on them, or with a certain emblem?

Thanks

Comment: What's an "emblem"? How do you detect one?

Answer (score 0):

Emblems are stored as metadata using special `metadata::emblems` attribute.
You can get the emblem for needed file by executing the following command:

```
gio info -a "metadata::emblems" ~/folder/filename
```

So this can be scripted using `find`, `grep` with command like shown below:

`find ~/Desktop -type f -exec sh -c "gio info -a metadata::emblems '{}' | grep emblems && echo '^ found in {}'" \;`

on my Ubuntu MATE and Xubuntu systems it returns the icon with emblem:

> ```
>  metadata::emblems: [development]
> ^ found in /home/user/Desktop/filename
> ```

Searching for certain emblem is possible, you can adapt the search command by yourself.